# how to get all the posts upvoted be current user using acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, acts-as-votable

i want to show all the posts users have upvoted on, how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have such models

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_voter
end
```

To get all upvoted posts of some user (e.g. `current_user`)

```
current_user.get_up_voted(Post)
```

Please also look at the [docs](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter)